# Is there a way to skip a task/play when files are not found in ansible?

Tags: ansible

Below I posted an example of what I currently have but it doesn't resolve the issue.

ignore_errors still outputs the errors from the play but doesnt stop the tasks from completing. Is there a way to skip the play all together and move on to the next?

```
- name: replace static with delta file
  copy:
    src: "/home/docs/delta.{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    dest: "/usr/share/static"
    backup: yes
  ignore_errors: yes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a fileglob to prevent the task from running if the source file does not exist:

```
- name: replace static with delta file
  copy:
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: "/usr/share/static"
    backup: yes
  loop: "{{ query('fileglob', '/home/docs/delta.%s' % inventory_hostname) }}"
```

This fileglob will return either 0 or 1 results, so the task will be
skipped if there is no matching file.

Comment: this does exactly what i was looking for thank you? is it possible to apply this loop to similar modules for instance if i do a line in file replace based on regex matching from a delta file to a consistent file?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. The `fileglob` lookup simply returns a list of files that match the given pattern. What you do with the loop value in the *item* variable is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing which comes to my mind is to create task which will check if the directory exist:

```
- name: Playbook name
  hosts: all

  tasks:
  - name: Task name
    stat:
      path: [path to the file or directory you want to check]
    register: register_name
```

And the second task to work if directory exists:

```
  - name: Task name
    debug:
      msg: "The file or directory exists"
    when: register_name.stat.exists
```

Comment: That `stat` command won't work. `stat` runs on the remote host, but the source of `copy` is on the local host.